# Click solo en enlaces

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, sass

tengo un menu de navegación en bootstrap, le agregue la siguiente animación con css:

```
a,
a:hover,
a:active,
a:visited {
color: unset;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
}




.link {

display: block;
position: relative;
margin-inline: 25px;
font-size: 24px;
color: red;
}
.link__ {
&0 {
    &:before {
        content: "";
        width: 0;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);

        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;

        transition: width 3s ease-in-out;
    }

    &:hover {
        &:before {
            width: 100%;
            z-index: -1;
        }
    }
    }
    }
```

Como puedo hacer para que la animacion solo se muestre en el texto y no hasta el final del enlace, que tome el tamaño completo de cada texto. estoy trabajando con bootstrap PD

[image: Así se ven mis enlaces foto 1]

[image: Quiero que se vean como en la foto 2]

Comment: Comparte el codigo para que podamos revisar y replicar en todo caso, para poder ayudarte